Cannot initialize Flutter Local Notifications for Android setup
I'm implementing the plugin flutter_local_notifications both for Android an iOS. However, when I call the initializeNotification() method (see below) it throws this error:
E/flutter ( 7665): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_icon, The resource ic_launcher could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)
E/flutter ( 7665): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter ( 7665): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
E/flutter ( 7665): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7665): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:143:12)
E/flutter ( 7665): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7665): #3      NotificationHelper.initializeNotification (package:olympus_alpha/logic/notifications.dart:21:5)
E/flutter ( 7665): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7665): #4      main (package:olympus_alpha/main.dart:65:3)
E/flutter ( 7665): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7665): 

Here is the initialization method called in main.dart file:
initializeNotification() async {
    _configureLocalTimeZone();
    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

I've tried both using the default icon "@mipmap/ic_launcher" and a custom one called "app_icon" loaded in android/app/src/main/res/drawable. The same error appears in both cases.
